# How to assign html value from code behind with asp.net

Tags: html, code-behind

I am trying to assign an innerhtml value to a div from the code behind. Here is what ive got:

```
private void ModalBody()
{
    LoadTemplateOverride();
    divModalBody.InnerHtml = 
}
private void LoadTemplateOverride()
{
    string templateURL = String.Format("{0}/leadgen/eodemails/templatecontroller.aspx?eodid={1}", site.Get("InternalApiUrl"), Email.ID);
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(templateURL) as HttpWebRequest;

    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

    tbSubject.Text = response.Headers["EmailSubject"];
    tbBody.Text = (new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: What platform? ASP.NET?

Comment: This SO answer should be interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6797319/1068352

Comment: Actually ignore my previous comment (linked post is about getting content).

Comment: I guess that wasnt very clear. What i want to do is take    `(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();` and make it the innerhtml    `divModalBody.InnerHtml = (new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();` but everytime i do that it doesnt know what "response" is.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `Literal` control. It outputs whatever you put on its `Text` property to the rendered HTML.

Markup:

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Code behind:

```
Literal1.Text = "<div>Some <strong>nice</strong> HTML</div>";
```